# Error in docker (cannot find module I exported) , not a problem when running npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js

`Error: Cannot find module '../controllers/thermostatLogic'`

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:10-alpine
LABEL version="1.02"
RUN mkdir -p /app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /app
USER node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm audit fix
RUN ls
RUN cd ./controllers && ls
RUN mkdir uploads &&\
cd uploads &&\
touch uploadedFile.csv
RUN cd ..
RUN ls
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 1000
```

I run the `docker build -t hvacdoctor .` command and then. 
When it runs the ls command it returns:

```
 ---> Running in a6d2b49092ef
INSIDE
app.js
bin
controllers
env.js
exampleDevices.json
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
public
readme.md
routes
schema
test
views
yarn.lock
Removing intermediate container a6d2b49092ef
```

docker run hvacdoctordocke:latest

```
Error: Cannot find module '../controllers/t***Logic'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/controllers/fileLogic.js:8:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/routes/index.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
```

This all works with npm install & npm start without an error OUT of docker but why is this an issue within it?

I've tried a few different methods (git clone is out though because i need SSO for that etc)

```
These are the install instructions
1) download bash / node
2) create a folder called uploads and a file called uploadedFile.csv -make sure the file is in the folder.
3) npm install 
4) npm start
```

Edit - here is a screenshot of the current folder structure.

[image: folder structure]

Thoughts?

Edit - it was suggested I run the program with the following docker-compose.yml

```
node-app:
  container_name: node-app
  image: node:latest
  restart: always
  volumes:
   - ./:/home/node/app
  working_dir: /home/node/app
  ports:
   - 4000:4000
  networks:
   - main-network
  command: "tail -f /dev/null && npm start"


Changed package.json

"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm i nodemon -g",
  "start": "nodemon index.js",
}
```

^^ WITH this suggested start script nodemon starts index.js recursively - if I remove nodemon from the command it cannot find index.js. - I will likely edit this as it is in the routes folder to start as routes/index.js

ALSO to add clarity - previously I did not work with nodemon - I was running NPM start to start my project if that makes a difference (i.e I can git clone and run npm install && npm start and it will work.

Comment: Could you share a link to the github project? I'd like to try to see the issue myself

Comment: I have it in a private repo some things I can share some I cannot. 

I can walk you through what the install steps would be if you were to git clone it though

1) download bash / node
2) create a folder called uploads and a file called uploadedFile.csv -make sure the file is in the folder.
3) npm install 
4) npm start

then go to localhost etc

Comment: Update this in your Dockerfile
`RUN cd ../..
RUN ls
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 1000`
I think you are running `npm start` from the controllers' folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below docker configuration for a node application. It will work for you.

```
 node-app:
  container_name: node-app
  image: node:latest
  restart: always
  volumes:
   - ./:/home/node/app
  working_dir: /home/node/app
  ports:
   - 4000:4000
  networks:
   - main-network
  command: "tail -f /dev/null && npm start"
```

Here below is package.json

```
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm i nodemon -g",
  "start": "nodemon index.js",
}
```

Comment: Does the configuration get pasted straight into my dockerfile or a file named docker config or something?

Comment: You just need to create one file in main directory 'docker-compose.yml' and paste this configuration it will work.

Comment: Thank you, and then I still run the same commands in dockerfile right?

Comment: You just need to run "node-app" container.

Comment: My node app won’t start properly from index.js it seems. I throw an error - I believe it starts from app.js but I get a different error.

Comment: I realize I had nodemon installed in my package.json but I never really ran nodemon.

Comment: This script " `scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm i nodemon -g",
  "start": "nodemon app.js",
} ` in package.json will install and run your app through nodemon.

Comment: I think the node user doesn't have permission to run `npm i nodemon -g` as I'm getting `npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules.`

I know not to do chmod 777 cause its not a good security move, how else might I avoid these permission errors?

Comment: I think you should create a user ''any user" on a server then clone the project on the server.

Comment: I can't github it as SSO is enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it could not find it as my mac is not type sensitive but ubuntu is. Standardizing my file names fixed it.

This dockerfile worked fine

```
FROM node:12.14.0-alpine
LABEL version="1.02"

#create working directories etc.
RUN mkdir -p /app

# Create a /App Directory to install the application in
WORKDIR /app

# Copy all files from the main project to the container
COPY . /app/

RUN npm install
# COPY package*.json ./app/
# RUN npm install
# Standard npm commands
## DELETE THE FOLLOWING WHEN DOCKER CONTAINER IS FIXED
RUN cd node_modules

# create an uploads directory , go into it and add a placeholder file to avoid bug.
RUN mkdir uploads
RUN touch uploads/uploadedFile.csv
#go back into root folder
# RUN cd ..
# RUN ls

# start project and expose port 3000 as localhost
CMD node ./bin/www
EXPOSE 3000
```